Files size changed after copying them between external hard drives
I just copied ~120G worth of data from one hard drive to another one (I have both mounted at the same time while copying the files). But what caught my attention was that some files are taking more space after being copied.
This doesn't happen with every single file, but the final size of the folder (which itself contains multiple folders and files) is significantly larger (118G originally and 153G after being copied). Can someone help me understand?
As these screenshots show looks like the space was being allocated in blocks of 128K, which I can kind of understand.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.



Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use [code block]s to format them

Also, how did you do the copying? GUI (which application)? CLI (which command, what arguments)? And which filesystems were involved?

Do you mean size (as reported by ls -l for instance) or disk usage (as reported by du or ls -s for instance)

@muru I copied them using ctrl + c and pasted using ctrl + v

@StéphaneChazelas both, I compared files size using ll and ls -1sh and also disk usage using du -sh

There are two common reasons why files would grow when copied.
If the original file had holes (unallocated sections) in it and you use a naive copy tool, the holes may get filled in with real zeros.  Jpeg files do not contain holes, so that's not it.
The other common reason would be that the files are being copied between two filesystems with different allocation block sizes.   Both copies of the files will have the same length (number of bytes), but as filesystems typically store files in blocks, files are always occupy an integer number of blocks.  The last few bytes of a file will partially fill the last block of a file.
If the target filesystem uses a larger block size, the last block of each file may be larger, and the storage size of the file will essentially be rounded up.
Historically, there have been several filesystems (original FFS, BSD UFS2, BTRFS) that tried to keep "fragment" blocks that would store the last partial blocks of multiple files in the same fragment block.

Several FS support inline compression which affect disk usage as well

Though not mentioned in the question, directories when copied between two identical FS tend to get smaller on the target as they are being created fresh there so not encumbered with space used by former entries since deleted.

source is NTFS and destination is exFAT, so I am guessing that's it

FAT is particularly bad about having a large block size.  EXFAT is probably just as bad or worse, especially if it's large.
