rsync destination is larger than source somehow?
OS is Debian. I am simply trying to make backups from one drive to another. Both drives are the exact same size, same filesystem, and the destination is empty to start with.
I'm running rsync like so:
rsync -a --info=progress2 /mnt/data/ /mnt/backup_data
This fails with rsync telling me the destination is full, and when I look with df, the destination is using more disk space than the source.
How is this possible? I'm just trying to make a simple backup. What am I doing wrong?
I want my backup drive to be an identical copy of the source drive.
Source filesystem is xfs, block size 4096. Destination filesystem is xfs, block size 4096.

Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/773560/files-size-changed-after-copying-them-between-external-hard-drives/773561#773561

Anything unexpected when you compare ls -l /mnt/data and ls -l /mnt/backup_data? What does df -h look like? If the directory structures under both mountpoints are identical: what does du -sm /mnt/data/* and du -sm /mnt/backup_data/*  tell you?

Are any of the files that you are copying sparse (e.g. disk images or other preallocated large files)?

If you are copying sparse files, you should tell rsync about it using the --sparse option. Otherwise it may waste space.
